# What is the first instruction to be executed by CPU when we switch on the PC?

Tags: io, boot, bootloader, bios

Recently I have been reading the booting.
on the booting I have the following questions?

I know `JMP 0xfffffff0` is the first instruction that is executed by the CPU after it receives the `POWERGOOD SIGNAL` by clock circuit here my questions are

**1) who will load that address in the CPU registers.**

**2)BIOS ROM contents will be copied to RAM exactly at what time means (whether before loading the address in to the CPU registers or after CPU executes the JMP instruction.)**

**please also please provide any manuals which illustrate what exactly happen when we switch on the PC.**

I want to explain this concept for seminar purpose in my college so that's why I want know more internals to answer the question that will trigger at the time of seminar.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about Desktop CPUs I think that nothing is better than Intel presentations.

http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/intelligent-systems/intel-boot-loader-development-kit/minimal-intel-architecture-boot-loader-paper.html

The BIOS is memory mapped, when you read a special address you are reading from NVRAM and not from the actual RAM.
The address 0xfffffff0 is part of that area. So in the Firmware of your motherboard a really basic bootloader that initialized disks, find the boot one and loads the read bootloader in RAM.

Comment: Please give me some related answers